# c# change bool state

Tags: unity-game-engine, boolean, state

Why this code can't change bool move to true on Update? Obstacle.Move change bool move to true, but not on Update(). Maybe it's simple problem, but i can't solve this. Thanks for answer.

*PlayerMove script:*

```
    Vector3 pos;
    public float speed;
    Obstacle obstacle;

    void Start () {

        obstacle = new Obstacle();
        pos = transform.position;

    }

    void Update () {

        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.LeftArrow))
            pos.x -= speed;

        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.RightArrow))
            pos.x += speed;

        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.UpArrow))
            pos.y += speed;

        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.DownArrow))
            pos.y -= speed;



        transform.position = pos;
    }

    void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D col)
    {
        if (col.CompareTag("side_collider"))
            print("side");


        else if (col.CompareTag("obstacle"))
        {
            obstacle.Move(true);
            print("obstacle");
        }
```

*Obstacle script:*

```
    Vector3 pos;
    public GameObject player;
    bool move = false;

    void Start () {

        pos = transform.position;
    }
    public bool Move(bool mo)
    {
        if(mo)
            move = true; // move <- true
        return move;
    }

    void Update () {


        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.LeftArrow))
            move = false;

        if (move) // but here is move <- false
            transform.localPosition = player.transform.position;

    }
```

Comment: First you can't use `new` to create a MonoBehaviour derived class. Second, what did you try to change the bool in Update? Currently there is no code to set it to true in Update.

Comment: When I use GetComponent<Obstacle>();, i get error: NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object PlayerMove.OnTriggerEnter2D

Comment: i set bool move = true on Move() and i want same bool value on Update. Can you help me? :)

Comment: GunnarB got your problem right. Please Edit your question and upload the whole `Obstacle` class. Also what is the name of GameObject `Obstacle` class is attched to. If there is none, that's fine but I need that info.

Comment: If `Obstacle` is not on the same object as `PlayerMove` (which it probably isn't) then you need to do something like `obstacle = GameObject.FindWithTag("obstacle").GetComponent<Obstacle>();` (seems like you have that tag). If you use `OnTriggerEnter2D` to call `Move()` and don't need the obstacle further more, you don't need that variable and just say `col.gameObject.GetComponent<Obstacle>().Move()`.

Comment: Actually you most likely want the latter because you will most likely have more than one obstacle and the find would not be distinct.

Comment: There is photos with my problem: https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=C7A243435ECAB1C0!2726&authkey=!ANJd6yak5SV7C60&ithint=folder%2cpng

Comment: You player object has duplicate components. Should anything happen if the player hits a side collider? If that should be the same as hitting the "main" part of the obstacle, use only one tag for the whole collider and then use `col.transform.root.GetComponent<Obstacle>().Move(true);`.

Comment: when player hits a side first collider, player can't move on the up, when second collider - can't right and third collider - can't down. So far it is not done.

Comment: Ok, anyways you should use `col.gameObject.GetComponent<Obstacle>().Move(true);` in your `OnTriggerEnter2D`. This will set your move bool to true. Note though if this happened using the left arrow it will be set to false again before your movement part. And by the looks of it you populate the `player` variable of Obstacle by hand via the inspector (otherwise you will get a NullReferenceException currently). You should use `player = GameObject.FindWithTag("Player");` for that in `Start()` (that is your current player tag).

Comment: Also I don't see a reason why you store the position of player and obstacle as field.

Comment: One more problem: 
How nonstop checks that the object is still in a collider?

Comment: @Adam there is `OnTriggerStay2D`: http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnTriggerStay2D.html

Comment: @GunnarB. 
I've found it. Thanks  :)